# Can not change text input color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the input color to white on the following element:

```
<textarea name="message" id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" required="" style="height: 45px;"></textarea>
```

Adding `color: white !important;` to the id, class or textarea does not work, in the developer tools it does work when I add the rule to:

```
input:not([type]), input[type=text]:not(.browser-default), input[type=password]:not(.browser-default), input[type=email]:not(.browser-default), input[type=url]:not(.browser-default), input[type=time]:not(.browser-default), input[type=date]:not(.browser-default), input[type=datetime]:not(.browser-default), input[type=datetime-local]:not(.browser-default), input[type=tel]:not(.browser-default), input[type=number]:not(.browser-default), input[type=search]:not(.browser-default), textarea.materialize-textarea
```

When I add the color rule to the local file on the same line it does not get applied for some reason, how can I change this text input color to white?

Comment: I have a feeling your used a id styling on one of the containers. If you want to override it. Try to include the id of that container as well. An example:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/hotv4wj0/3/

In order to solve that you can include textarea to the id as well like this:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jz41eyat/

What you also can do is including the id to it like this:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jz41eyat/2/

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some overrides issue:

```css
#textarea1{
color: #fff;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="message" id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" required="" style="height: 45px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in this [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/74569/), therefore you most likely have another rule further down your CSS file which is overriding your setting. Failing that you could always make `color: #ffffff !important;` but this is less desirable if you can fix it the other way.

(Note: I've used pink in the jsfiddle to make sure it's actually working)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BPGRhLkd This is the stylesheet from Materialize but with some custom rules, do you know where I should put it?

Comment: You are probably best just adding a new class to the textarea, and defining that new class at the bottom of your CSS styles.

Comment: i think you should advice to use !important in css, it is a bad practice to use it , rather make a new css that overwrites previous css and put it after the prev css file so it will overrule the prev css

Answer (score 0):

```css
#textarea1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="message" id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" required="" style="height: 45px;"></textarea>
```

Your problem is probably an `CSS` [priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) conflict where another style is overriding your style. You can solve this by choosing a higher priority or use !important after a style.

Comment: I tried to add a class to it and add the important rule on my custom stylesheet and in the Materialize stylesheet at the bottom but it is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked using default CSS ways but got it to work by adding this to the textarea in the HTML:

```
style="color: white !important;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a new answer. This is the most aggressive specficity in `CSS` this should override the older ones. Try this:

`<textarea id="textarea1" style="color:white !important;"></textarea>`

This combines the inline specifity with the !important specficity which are both really high (!important highest, inline second highest)

Hopefully this works.